# How to keep a users selection even after they close the app? Android

Tags: java, android, xml

So at the moment the user will select a colour, shape and time. When the app first starts up there is a default for each. What I want to happen is to keep the users selection for all 3 of these even after they close the app while it runs in the background.

If you need me to post anything to help ask away. Thanks.

After writing out what the problem was, it's not that they're not being saved it's the fact that the selections ARE being saved but not being displayed properly. I.E by a border or the dropdown menu results back to it's default value instead of the users selection.

So the values are being saved(my bad) but the app overwrites these saves and doesn't use the border or beings the dropdown menu back to it's default value.

```
 circularImageView = (CircularImageView)findViewById(R.id.activity_main_silver_color_button);
    circularImageView.setBorderColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.unselected_border));

circularImageView = (CircularImageView)findViewById(v.getId());
    circularImageView.setBorderColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.selected_border));
```

These work independent of each other but when the border is selected, if a another color was selected then it becomes an unselected border. But what happens if "selected_border" state is never saved.

```
public static void saveLockScreenDuration(Context context, int duration){
    getStoredPreferences(context).edit().putInt(SELECTED_DURATION, duration).apply();

public static int getLockScreenDuration(Context context){
    return getStoredPreferences(context)
            .getInt(SELECTED_DURATION, DEFAULT_DURATION);
}
```

This is where all the prefereces are stored. DEFAULT_DURATION and SELECTED_DURATION are in a class called constants.

Comment: So basically you want to save the user's selection everytime it is updated?

Comment: try saving the user's selection in a SharedPreference. then when the view is being created, load the saved SharedPreference. refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3624358/908821

Comment: Yep thats basically what I'm looking for

Comment: @AngelKoh I have them going into a SharedPreference but my Default Value is static and I'm not sure how to change it so it'll change even when the app is in the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon selection you can store selected values in Shared Preferences. And upon launching it again you can check if those values are null or not. And display accordingly. Read how to use Shared Preferences [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3624358/3746306).

Comment: It does save the values but once the app goes into the background they don't save, and I have no idea why,

Comment: Correct me if wrong, how user would change his colour preferences once app goes in background. since it won't be visible to user. Then what is it that you want to save when app is in background?

Comment: After writing out what the problem was, it's not that they're not being saved it's the fact that the selections ARE being saved but not being displayed properly. I.E by a border or the dropdown menu results back to it's default value instead of the users selection.

Comment: Would you please post your activity code of saving data and using it back.

Comment: I've added it there to the main post, the code that saves and changes

Comment: Where exactly you have extracted user selected colours from shared preferences ?

Comment: Added the class to the main post too

Comment: Both methods are correct `saveLockScreenDuration` and `saveLockScreenDuration` but it is important to see how you are accessing these two from activity class and respective logic written in activity. So please post your activity logic where you have stored and accessed these values

Comment: `PreferencesStore.saveLockScreenDuration(this, index);

        OptionsActivity.setTimeout(this, PreferencesStore.getLockScreenDuration(this));`

I think I know what you mean. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Is it written in `onCreate()` or in `onRestart()`

Comment: It's in it's own method called onTimeDurationChanged

Comment: I think I know where you're getting at now, thanks for the help. I'll play around with this

Comment: All you need to do is set your default configuration in `onCreate` then user would select his preferences accordingly. - Now assume app goes in background. -Now app comes to foreground. In `onRestart`  check if user has updated his selection by getting values using `PreferencesStore.getLockScreenDuration(this)`  and then update your UI according to this value.

Answer (score 0):

if you talking about for activity restore data.
then see here.
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html#saras

Comment: Any idea what I should if the values are inside public void method?

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if i am wrong. I think you can use `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context context)`

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

which is shared across all your Activity and Service classes. If you set an accessibility service to get the event when app is in background and used defaultsharedprefrences to store i think it will work for your case.

Comment: Thanks, but I've made a mistake in what I was saying it's all saving perfectly fine, but the border around the selected values aren't if that make sense.